# JOIN mySQL к одной таблице

Tags: join, mysql

Привет. Не могу разобраться с чередой джоинов:

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.NAME SEPARATOR ', ') CONTACT_LIST,
    c.NAME COMPANY
FROM
    qcrm_contact_link rel
    JOIN deals a ON a.ID = rel.ID_DEAL
    JOIN contacts b ON b.ID = rel.ID_CONTACT AND b.ELEMENT_TYPE=1
    LEFT JOIN contacts c ON c.ID = rel.ID_CONTACT AND c.ELEMENT_TYPE=3
WHERE 
    a.ACCOUNT_ID=9376317
GROUP BY
    a.ID
```

Задача простая - вывести элементы из таблицы contacts с разными ELEMENT_TYPE в разные столбцы

Ожидаю получить заполненный столбец COMPANY, но он пуст:

```
NAME        CONTACT                             COMPANY
test_deal_1 test_contact_1, test_contact_2      NULL
test_deal_2 test_contact_1                      NULL
```

Если убрать LEFT из последнего JOIN, вообще везде будет NULL

Я же вроде применяю алиасы, почему таблицы b и с зависимы друг от друга? Как можно пофиксить?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте пример на http://sqlfiddle.com может быть все что угодно вплоть до синтаксической опечатки.
вот например:

```
     JOIN qcontacts b
LEFT JOIN contacts c
```

таблицы разные, а вы вроде бы хотели из одной...

Comment: Да, это я опечатался когда упрощал пример для Хешкода

Я менял кучу раз все местами, делал чтобы COMPANY отображалось - тогда пропадает CONTACT

Тут какой-то глобальный косяк, мне не хватает опыта понять в чем дело

Comment: @silent-box, создайте пример на http://sqlfiddle.com